# Disable Content of Button WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a simple override of the Control Template for a button in WPF that looks like this.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="ButtonRectangle" Fill="{StaticResource BlueBrush}"/>
        <ContentPresenter Panel.ZIndex="1"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

Typically the button will contain text "OK", "Cancel", etc.  If the button is ever disabled I want the text Foreground property to update to a disabled text style.  I haven't found any way to let the content in the content presenter know that it is disabled.  Where am I going wrong with this one?

Comment: why not use a `Trigger` to change the `TextElement.Foreground` property?

Comment: @HighCore - That works if the Content property is set to some text.  What if the content is a TextBlock or Label?

Comment: @BrianTriplett Isnt this automatic? I put a sample together to see if it wasn't the case and I can't reproduce your problem. [Sample Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vxvm16izfz4nfw/WpfApplication38.rar) Content of the `Button` does get disabled when the button is disabled. Also I hope your code was just for the sake of this sample, since you could drop your Grid and Rectangle and just use a `Border` for the `ContentPresenter` and achieve the same that you have.